# Bring the button to next line and centre position. Keep the background image to full size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.home{
    background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/27/21/03/lone-tree-1934897_960_720.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.hero-text{
 font-size:32px;
}

.btn-hero{
    position:relative;
    font-size:20px;
    background:transparent;
    border:2px solid #282828;
    border-radius:28px;
    padding:10px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
 <h1 class="hero-text">Everything Starts with Your Awesome Website</h1>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-hero">Create Now</button>
</div>
```

I want to bring the button to next line and centre position text and button.
Here I also want to have the background image to fill the size of device according to the height.

Comment: should Images  cover the text?

Comment: @KiranPurbey consider this as home page, where the text and button must come over the image. Similar to this home page: http://www.wix.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add flex-direction: column to .home and add text-align: center to .hero-text. Add background-size: cover to .home to fill the background.

```css
.home{
 background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/27/21/03/lone-tree-1934897_960_720.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    backgroud-size: cover;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.hero-text{
 font-size:32px;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn-hero{
 font-size:20px;
 background:transparent;
 border:2px solid #282828;
 border-radius:28px;
 padding:10px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
 <h1 class="hero-text">Everything Starts with Your Awesome Website</h1>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-hero">Create Now</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use This code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .home{
        background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/27/21/03/lone-tree-1934897_960_720.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width:100%;
        height:500px;
        max-width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: -15px 0px;
      }
      .hero-text{
        font-size:32px;
      }

      .btn-hero{
        position:relative;
        font-size:20px;
        background:transparent;
        border:2px solid #282828;
        border-radius:28px;
        padding:10px 30px;
        z-index: 999;
        color:white;
      }
      body{margin: 0px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="home">
        <h1 class="hero-text">Everything Starts with Your Awesome Website</h1>
     </div>
      <div style="text-align: center;margin-top: -150px;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-hero">Create Now</button>
      </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The button has to be immediate below the text. But it goes blow the image. Both the text and button has to be over the image and centred.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.home{
   position: relative;
      background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/27/21/03/lone-tree-1934897_960_720.jpg");
      size:cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 100vh;
     align-items: center;
       justify-content: center;
      background-size:cover;
    
  
    }
    .hero-text{
        font-size:32px;
    }

    .btn-hero{
      position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        font-size:20px;
        background:transparent;
        border:2px solid #282828;
        border-radius:28px;
        padding:10px 30px;

    }
```

```html
<div class="home">
    <h1 class="hero-text">Everything Starts with Your Awesome Website</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-hero" style="position:center">Create Now</button>
</div>
```

```
.home{
      background-image:url ("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/27/21/03/lone-tree-1934897_960_720.jpg");
      size:cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 100vh;
     align-items: center;
       justify-content: center;
      background-size:cover;
    }
    .hero-text{
        font-size:32px;
    }

    .btn-hero{
      position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        font-size:20px;
        background:transparent;
        border:2px solid #282828;
        border-radius:28px;
        padding:10px 30px;

    }
```

```html
<div class="home">
    <h1 class="hero-text">Everything Starts with Your Awesome Website</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-hero" style="position:center">Create Now</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The button is centred. But I need both the text and button to be at the centre.  Similar to this home page: wix.com

Answer (score 1):

Is this okay ??

```css
.home{
   position: relative;
      background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/27/21/03/lone-tree-1934897_960_720.jpg");
      size:cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 100vh;
     align-items: center;
       justify-content: center;
      background-size:cover;
    
  
    }
    .hero-text{
    position: absolute;
     top: 25%;
    left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        font-size:32px;
        background:transparent;
        padding:0px 0px;
    }

    .btn-hero{
      position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        font-size:20px;
       background:transparent;
        border:2px solid #282828;
        border-radius:28px;
        padding:10px 30px;

    }
```

```html
<div class="home">
    <h1 class="hero-text">Everything Starts with Your Awesome Website</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-hero" >Create Now</button>
</div>
```